# Intuition on formal neighborhood in a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme, $x \in X$ a closed point. Denote by $\hat X$ the completion of $X$ along $x$. Now assume that two coherent modules $F, G$ on $X$ coincide over $\hat X$, i.e. $i^*F = i^*G$ for the natural morphism $i: \hat X \to X$. When do we have $F = G$ in a neighborhood of $x$?

My intuition says to me that $\hat X$ is something like a neighborhood of $x$, but of course it should be considered only as a formal neighborhood. So probably, if there is some smoothness assumption on $X$ around $x$, then we may drop *formally*, i.e. each formal neighborhood gives us a "real" one?

I would appreciate any hint, explanation, reference or an example.

*EDIT:* Regarding the comments the equalities $i^*F = i^* G$ and $F=G$ should/could be considered as $i^*F \cong i^* G$ and $F \cong G$.

Comment: When you write $i^*F=i^*G$, you should suppose $F$ and $G$ are subsheaves of a same sheaf $H$. Otherwise, it is hard to think about equality. Anyway, under my assumption, one can replace $G$ by $F+G$ and thus suppose that $F$ is a subscheaf $G$. Now the hypothesis can be stated as $i^*(G/F)=0$, and you want to prove $G/F=0$. This is typically a situation where the notion of faithful flatness intervenes.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should replace the equality by isomorphism.

Comment: They could also be quotients of the same sheaf, as in the example I gave (quotients of the structure sheaf of X). Certainly there would need to be <i>some</i> notion of comparability between $F$ and $G$.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on Cantlog's observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realised after writing this that I had misread your question - I thought you wanted $i^*F$ and $i^*G$ to be isomorphic, but you actually said they should be equal. Still, here are my thoughts.

==

A formal neighborhood is definitely smaller than a Zariski-open neighborhood. It can be helpful to think of $\hat{X}$ as the union or direct limit of all infinitesimal neighborhoods of $x$ in $X$, where "infinitesimal neighborhood" means a subscheme $Y \subset X$, probably nonreduced, that is only supported at $x$. (This fits with the inverse limit on the algebraic side, since Spec is contravariant.)

A nice example showing the difference: let $X = \text{Spec}\ k[x,y]$, $\hat{X} = k[[x,y]]$, the completion of $X$ at the origin. Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be, respectively, the structure sheaves $k[x,y] / (x^2 - y^2)$ and $k[x,y] / (y^2 - x^2(x+1))$. These are, respectively, the union of the lines $y = \pm x$, and the nodal cubic with node at the origin, having tangent lines $y = \pm x$.

In this case, $i^*\mathcal{F}$ and $i^* \mathcal{G}$ are actually isomorphic, but not equal, on any infinitesimal neighborhood of the origin, since both curves look infinitesimally like two arcs meeting at a point. You can see this isomorphism on the level of power series: $\frac{k[[x,y]]}{(y-x)(y+x)} \cong \frac{k[[x,y]]}{(y-x\sqrt{x+1})(y+x\sqrt{x+1})}$, using the Taylor series for $\sqrt{x+1}$, which is a unit in $k[[x,y]]$.

Of course, the two curves are neither equal nor isomorphic on any open neighborhood of the origin, since their local rings are different (the first is not a domain, but the second is.)

Anyway, you asked about equality, and in the above example, $i^*\mathcal{F}$ is not equal to $i^*\mathcal{G}$, since the arcs are actually different arcs (except for the first-order neighborhood, since they have the same tangent lines).

I'm not totally sure, but I think the answer to your question is yes and follows from something like the theorem on formal functions (Hartshorne III.11.1), though note that it has no smoothness assumptions. I think you want to consider the sheaf $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{Hom(F,G)}$. The theorem says that $\mathcal{R} \otimes k[[x,y]]$ is the inverse limit of the restrictions of $\mathcal{R}$ to infinitesimal neighborhoods. If $i^*F = i^*G$ on $\hat{X}$, then there's an "identity map" $\hat{\varphi} \in \mathcal{R} \otimes k[[x,y]]$. So certainly $\mathcal{R}$ can't be too small (e.g. it can't be 0), and we can write

$\hat{\varphi} = \varphi_1 \otimes f_1 + \cdots + \varphi_n \otimes f_n,$

for some maps $\varphi_i \in \mathcal{R}$ and power series $f_i \in k[[x,y]]$. I'm not sure how to complete this argument, I'm afraid.

SECOND EDIT:

Faithful flatness is what I was forgetting - never mind the theorem on formal functions. The answer to the "equality" version of the question is yes: following Cantlog's suggestion in the comments, suppose $F$ and $G$ are comparable, say $F$ is a subsheaf of $G$, and $i^*F = i^*G$. Then $i^*(G/F)$ is zero, and by faithful flatness of $\hat{O}_{x,x}$ over $O_{x,X}$, this forces $G/F \otimes O_{x,X}$ to be zero (where $O_{x,X}$ is the local ring of $x \in X$), so $F = G$ over the local ring. Hence they are equal on an open neighborhood, since everything is finitely-generated.

Hopefully that completes the answer to your question!

Comment: Thank you. I made the question needlessly complicated by speaking about equalities, where isomorphisms are perfectly fine.